# Effect on mass of change of angle on hinged beam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, continuum-mechanics

I am trying to calculate the change in weight (if any) on point B of a beam hinged at point A if the angle changes. e.g. A bridge hinged on solid ground (Point A) reaching onto a floating pontoon (Point B) where the tide rises and falls.

[image: Drawing of beam]

Comment: You need to provide a drawing

Comment: Thanks Bob, I have now added a drawing.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @Jimbo Last questions. When you say the "weight" on B can I assume you mean the  downward force on the pontoon? Also, can I assume the 1000 kg at mid point represents the weight of the beam concentrated at the mid point?

Comment: Hi again Bob, the answer is yes to both questions, the overall weight of the beam is 1 tonne and when horizontal I understand the downward force would be 500 kg at both point A and point B. However as point B drops and swivels around point A I need to know how the downward force on point B is affected. To be clear point B will be supported on a float which will drop with the tide.

Answer (score 0):

We do not solve homework and exercise problems on this site.  The following is offered for guidance to help you visualize the problem and asking you questions to think about your own answer.

The top diagram below shows the beam at mid tide.

The middle and lower diagrams show tide up and tide down, respectively (the vertical support of the hinge in each diagram should be vertical, not tilted as shown as because I simply rotated the entire picture). For the beam to be in equilibrium in any of the diagrams, the sum of the vertical forces acting on the beam have to equal zero, and the algebraic sum of the moments acting about any point on the beam (including the hinge) has to equal zero.

**RISING TIDE (Middle diagram):**

When the tide rises it increases the angle between the beam and the horizontal. Additionally, part of the length of the beam to the left becomes submerged.

*QUESTION: How will partial submersion of the beam effect the downward force on the pontoon at B?*

Second, as the tide rises the angle the beam makes with the horizontal increases.

*QUESTION: How will the increase in angle affect the upward reaction force at the hinge? At the pontoon?*

**FALLING TIDE (Bottom diagram):**

When the tide falls (bottom diagram, exaggerated), the angle becomes negative and now the end of the beam to the right of the midpoint drops along with the pontoon.

*QUESTION: How will an increase in the negative angle between the beam and the horizontal  affect the downward force on the pontoon?. Suppose the angle was $-90^o$ and the pontoon separated from the beam so that the beam was hanging by the hinge?*

If you can answer these questions, you will know how the rising and falling tides (changes in angle of the beam with the horizontal) affect the downward force on the pontoon.

Hope this helps
[image]